# Évidentialité et Passé Simple

Tags: temps-grammatical, linguistique, passé-simple

I've been reading about [Évidentialité](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89videntialit%C3%A9), and I was wondering if Passé Simple, as a tense which is usually used for historical events, and in the third person, can be considered as a form of Evidentiality. For example, I've found this claim in the book "La ligne claire: De la linguistique à la grammaire".
[image]

Comment: Excellent question. I suspect it doesn't have an evidential dimension now, but may have in the past. The answer will require someone more widely read in French.

Answer (score 1):

Ce qui suit est plus une manière d'alimenter la discussion qu'une réponse.

---

Je contracte un peu le propos de Wiberg:

> *Wiberg croit pouvoir ramener les emplois journalistiques du passé simple à deux fonctions [illocutoire](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonction_illocutoire)s et propose de rapprocher sa valeur [modalisatrice](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modalisateur) au paradigme de l'[évidentialité](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89videntialit%C3%A9).*

Il semble que c'est *sous hypothèse* d'illocution que le passé simple puisse ainsi être rapproché du paradigme d'évidentialité. Ca en devient presque pléonastique.

Si on considère l'emploi du passé simple comme un moyen d'user d'une fonction illocutoire historique dans le cadre de notre narration, alors c'est l'intérêt même d'expliciter la source informationnelle (de l'évidence) qui s'évanouit.

J'en conclurais sous cette hypothèse que l'emploi du passé simple can be considered as an evidentiality of type [indirective](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89videntialit%C3%A9#Indirectivit%C3%A9_(type_I)).